# bootstrap align vertically content in the middle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can i align vertically the content in the middle of the column?
this is my [jsffidle](http://jsfiddle.net/2cPcA/548/) , I would like that the text in the left column is align vertically in the center of column
is there a special class of bootstrap?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 ">
        <span class="v-align">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</span>
    </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <img class="pull-right img-responsive" style="margin-top:10px;"src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000" />

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
.row {
    display: table;
}

[class*="col-"] {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: i prefer your solution, do you know if it is cross browser?

Comment: Yes it is. You can use .col-sm-6 instead [class*="col-"] which is attribute selector. I am not sure that you need all that clases, so if you want try to use just .col-sm-6. I would appreciate if you mark this as "answered".

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this,
this will work but we need to give the height to that span.

just like below :-

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 ">
        <span class="v-align" style="vertical-align: middle; display: table-cell; height: 565px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</span>
    </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <img class="pull-right img-responsive" style="margin-top:10px;" src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000" />

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `<center>` will center the text, and using the `<div>` tag with the attribute `align` set to `center` will do the same. If you want the element to be centered in the page, using `<table>` [should work (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/jczj5gLx/):

```
<html>
Lorem Ipsum something something.
<table align="center">
    <tr><td width="20%">Hello</td></tr>
</table>
</html
```

Answer (score 0):

posible solution with some JS (need small adds for responsive layout):
https://jsfiddle.net/muzd1prc/

```
.v-align-container{
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.v-align{
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".v-align-container img").bind('load', function(event) {
        var $row = $(this).parents(".v-align-container:first");
        $row.height($row.height());            
    });
});
```